# Generate ES256 PrivateKey from String

Tags: android

I'm trying to build JWT token to use in [Appel Music API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens). to build the token i need to transfert a string (privatekey) that i got form the Appel API to Android [PrivateKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/PrivateKey) object based on SignatureAlgorithm ES256. I can't figure out how to make this happen. I only found methdes that generate random private/public keys like `Keys.keyPairFor(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256)`

Any help would be appreciated